# How to remove the hashtag #index.html# file in linux/unix?

Tags: linux, command-line, amazon-web-services, terminal

if I ls in terminal, i got this

```
#index.html#  Procfile  bootstrap index.html
```

And I want to remove this #index.html# file, how can I do so?

Typing

> rm -f #index.html#

doesn't work. Also, anyone know why is it there in the first place? I'm using aws EC2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#` is a special character: you must backslash it:

> rm -f \#index.html#

This file could appear if this directory is part of a CVS repository and there was a conflict on this file (see the man page of [cvs update](http://www-e815.fnal.gov/webspace/cvs/commands.html#update)).